# Creating instance of member variables

Tags: java, instance-variables

Hi this is a basic question, but kindly bear with me.

I have two classes and on class has a reference of another class. How can i create the instance of second class which is present in first class at the time creation of instance of first class. Are any utility present for this.

Code ::

```
class A  {
  B b;
}

class B {
 int member;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the wonderful answers but this was a simple scenario, for me class A has n references of some other classes and those classes themselves contain N references of other classes.

Comment: So you are saying your question is not really your question?  What is your actual question then if these answers don't help you?

Answer (score 2):

1. In a Contructor (like Robert Kock already said)

```
class A  {
  B b;

  public A(){
    b = new B();
    b.member = 5;
  }
}
```

2. Directly as Attribute

```
class A  {
  B b = new B(5);  
}
```

3. With Initializer

```
class A  {
  B b;
  {
    b = new B();
    b.member = 5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the constructor of the first class:

```
class A 
{
  public A()
  {
    b = new B();
  }

  B b;

}
```

Or even like this:

```
class A 
{
  public A()
  {
  }

  B b = new B();

}
```

Comment: Equivalently just change the declaration to `B b = new B();`.

Comment: What if A is not supposed to be responsible for creating an instance of B?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster then it probably shouldn't be creating them in its constructor. But that's what the question asked for.

Comment: Thanks for all the wonderful answers but this was a simple scenario, for me class A has n references of some other classes and those classes themselves contain N references of other classes. For Example :: class A { classA1 a1; classA2 a2; ... classAn An;}

Answer (score 1):

A general solution would be:

```
public class A {

    private final B b;

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }    
}

...

A a = new A(new B());
```

It becomes interesting when both instances refer to each other, then you need to use a setter in at least one of the classes:

```
public class B {

    private A a; // the field cannot be final in this case

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }    
}

....

B b = new B()
A a = new A(b);
b.setA(a);
```

The answers where the class is creating the other instance itself are not a general solution.